# No module named models when importing keys on jupyter

Tags: keras, jupyter-notebook

I have just recently been playing around with Jupyter and Keras.
I have created a virtualenv on my computer and created the corresponding kernel to be used on Jupyter.
The problem arises though when I try accessing keras modules.
If I do: import keras
I do not get any errors, however when I do the following:

from keras.models import Sequential

I get the following error:

```
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)

 < ipython-input-1-8d76137599c3 > in < module >

  1 
  2 
  3 ----> from keras.models import Sequential
  4 from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
  5 from keras.utils import np_utils

ImportError: No module named models
```

if someone would have any suggestions it would be great!!

thanks!!

Comment: Weird.... I suggest uninstalling keras and installing it again... (have you properly installed numpy, scipy and theano or tensorflow?)

Comment: I tried that already and it didn't really make any difference. I really don't understand because the module models clearly exists in my virtualenv
I tried importing keras  and the module models on the virtualenv directly on my computer's terminal (so not on the jupiter notebook) and it works. So now I wonder whether I did the kernel thing right, but I wouldn't see why I would be able to import tensorflow, theano, numpy etc if I hadn't..

Comment: Any luck? Im having same issue

Comment: i realized that i had a "keras" compiled file within the same folder - i initially assumed that was done because of the installation, but when I deleted it it worked. Not sure how that got there